# Angular 2/4 | Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Object[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm currently having a pretty weird bug that I can't solve. I have a SocketIoService with handles my socket.io websocket.

**SocketIoService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io';


@Injectable()
export class SocketioService {

    getRecentMessages(){
        this.socket.emit('messages');
        return this.socket
        .fromEvent("messages")
        .map( data => data );
    }


    constructor(private socket:Socket) {
        console.log('[i] socketio service connected');
    }

}
```

I subscribe to the observable getRecentMessages() from my ChatComponent

**Chat.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketioService } from '../../services/socketio.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chat',
    templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

    messages:Object[] = [];

    constructor(
        private socketioService:SocketioService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.socketioService.getRecentMessages().subscribe(messages => {
            console.log('SOCKET received chat/messages DATA', messages);
            this.messages = messages;
        });
    }


}
```

When Chat.Component.ts is initialized it subscribes to getRecentMessages(). That function then emits to my backend server and the server responds an array of the most recent messages. Looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/ecedc406fec48a4e1224ae2aa47844d0

I try to set the messages array equal to the response in Chat.Component.ts but I get the error Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Object[]'. That means somehow Angular/Typescript thinks that the response is an object instead of an array. How do I fix this? Thank you :)

Comment: socketioService.getRecentMessages() seems to return object, not array of objects. Try to print in console messages that you receive from service.

Comment: I did print it to console, the gyazo picture shows my console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:
Finally I found the solution.. I looked through the module ng-socket-io that I am using to handle socket.io. This function

https://gyazo.com/43a45d65ba56997f4ea401653cb75416

can take a type parameter for the observable. In my socketio.service I added it behind .fromEvent:

```
getRecentMessages(){
    this.socket.emit('messages');
    return this.socket
    .fromEvent<Object[]>("messages")
    .map( data => data );
}
```

Works perfectly now. Thanks to everyone that answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

Just change

From

```
  messages:Object[] = [];
```

To

```
  messages:any = [];
```

Comment: I get the same error:  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Comment: then your response is not an array

Comment: But I console logged the response in Chat.component.ts and in my console it shows an array of objects. You can see it in the gyazo screenshot

Comment: Thats also why this seems so weird to me, the code should work but it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

If the `getRecentMessages()` returns an array of strings, you should cast your observable to array, e.g.

```
this.socketioService.getRecentMessages()<string[]>.subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
messages:Object[] = [];
```

insted of

```
private messages: Array<any> = [];
```

Comment: Its not private

Comment: Also tried this but it doesn't work. I've pretty much given up at this point

Answer (score 0):

Try to create interface for object model, like:

```
export interface Message {
    _id: string,
    updated_at: Date,
    created_at: Date,
    ...
}
```

Then import into your component, and initialise variable as array of Message object:

```
messages: Message[];
```

Comment: Try using as: this.messages = messages as Message[];